# Can I use UseState to toggle data between two categories?

Tags: reactjs, filter, react-hooks, next.js, use-state

I have a list of shows with two categories. I have a menu to display all shows and a submenu supposed to filter the component datas  between the two categories.
Can I use a hook like useState to create that filter ? Is there a better way ?
I use nextjs with strapi.
Please me cool my brain ! :)

Here is my unfinished try. I don't know if I follow the right way

SubMenu.js

```
const SubMenu = ({ categories }) => {

// I tried to use state to store the 2 categories
    const [state, setState] = useState({
            initial: false,
            clicked: null,
            fondateurs : categories[0],
            soutenus : categories[1]
        });

     //state for disabled button
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);



    return (
        <>
            <ul className="sous-menu">
                {categories.map((cat) => (
                    <li key={cat.id}>
                        <a
                            // disabled={disabled}
                           // onClick={handleMenu}>
                            {cat.name}
                        </a>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </>
    )
}

export default SubMenu
```

Nav.js

```
const Nav = ({ categories }) => {
  
  return (
    <Navbar>        
      <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">    
        <ul className="menu">          
          <li >
            <ActiveLink activeClassName="active" as="/spectacles" href="/spectacles">
              <a>
                Spectacles
              </a>
            </ActiveLink>     
              <SubMenu categories={categories} />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
  )
}

export default Nav
```

Data model category

```
[
  {
    "id": "string",
    "title": "string",
    "description": "string",
    "year": 0,
    "author": "string",
    "image": {
      "id": "string",
      "name": "string",
      "alternativeText": "string",
      "caption": "string",
      "width": 0,
      "height": 0,
      "formats": {},
      "hash": "string",
      "ext": "string",
      "mime": "string",
      "size": 0,
      "url": "string",
      "previewUrl": "string",
      "provider": "string",
      "provider_metadata": {},
      "related": "string",
      "created_by": "string",
      "updated_by": "string"
    },
    "categories": [
      {
        "id": "string",
        "name": "string",
        "slug": "Unknown Type: uid",
        "nb": 0,
        "spectacle": "string",
        "created_by": "string",
        "updated_by": "string"
      }
    ],
    "published_at": "2021-09-23T15:51:39.752Z"
  }
]
```

Comment: `setToggle(toggle);` what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: It's to hide the submenu when Spectacles are not active. But nothing to do with the filter

Comment: `setToggle(toggle)` won't do anything. It is already set to `toggle`

Comment: Thank you, but this isn't my actual question

Comment: It is not very clear what the issue is. What is not going as expected with this?

Comment: The question is about filtering the submenu. I want to achieve this with states. by default all spectacles are displayed. When click on one the two categories, I want to display only the concerned spectacles

Comment: Is the `Nav` component (nav.js) a child of the relevant page that has all the shows?

Comment: A grand child exactly